# Relationship to a Spring Data Rest repository

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

We have a relationship, a @DBref, between two entities in the model managed with a Spring Data repository based on Mongo.

Now we have the need to provide one of these entities from a Rest service.

How can it be solved for automatically get the related entity retrieved from the Rest service when the primary entity is loaded? 
There is some kind of annotation to help with it like the @DBref do? Something like a @RESTref annotation?